# Determining the convergence of improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

I would like to prove the convergence of the following improper integral:

$$\int_1^2 {\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{16-x^4}}} dx\quad\quad $$

I tried to find antiderivative (with assistance of online calculators) and then check the limits, but was unable to do so.
Can anyone help with some direction?
Thanks.

Comment: Indefinite integral  is a synonym for antiderivative, so there is no sense to talking about convergence of an indefinite integral. Presumably, you are talking about an integral where the function goes to infinity as $x\to2.$ My brain is fried, and I'm blanking on the term for that, but it is no "indefinite."

Comment: Ah, yes, "improper integral" is the term you are seeking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the correction